# How to pass a url contains ? , / , & inside flask webservice method

Tags: python, regex, web-services, flask, request

I am trying to pass a URL inside a Flask method,

```
My url: https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk
```

I tried the below steps:

```
@app.route('/flip/<path:url>')
def flip(url):
    return "retrievved url:"+str(url)
    
calling the url : localhost:8200//flip/https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk 
returns : `https://example.org/de`

and another method,

@app.route('/flip')
def flip(url):
    url=request.args.get('url')
    return "retrievved url:"+str(url)

    
calling the url: localhost:8200//flip?url=https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk  
returns : 'https://example.org/de?=fg'
```

My expected output should return the entire url we are passing `https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk`

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with Flask. Your URLs don't mean what you think they mean.

For example, this URL:

```
localhost:8200//flip?url=https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk
```

… has two query parameters:

```
url=https://example.org/de?=fg
hi=jk
```

The `&` separates query parameters on the outer request, so it has separate `url` and `hi` parameters.

It's also illegal to have many of those characters in a query parameter in the first place, but you'll often get away with it.

---

This is why websites that need to embed URLs inside other URLs use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Your page should be sending this:

```
localhost:8200//flip?url=https%3A//example.org/de%3F%3Dfg%26hi%3Djk
```

Now there's only one query parameter:

```
url=https%3A//example.org/de%3F%3Dfg%26hi%3Djk
```

And then, when you parse the query string, what you get is:

```
url=https://example.org/de?=fg&hi=jk
```

---

If you really can't fix things on the client side, you may be able to iterate all the query parameters and trying to reassemble them into one `url` parameter.

Or you could get the entire URL (`request.url` instead of `request.args`), and do your own parsing on it manually instead of letting Flask or Python do it for you.

But either way, this is really hacky, and you shouldn't consider it unless absolutely necessary.

Plus, again, your URL is illegal, and you don't want to rely on "you'll often get away with it". Unless it's acceptable that, say, some users won't be able to connect because their proxy screws up the URLs, and you spent all weekend banging your head on the desk trying to debug it, and then it works for some of them but a few now get the wrong pages, and then the new version of Chrome is suddenly breaking something different, and…

HTTP is complicated and messy enough when you stick to the standards, especially since your framework does most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there any way to get output for my URL by considering the URL as string or any best way

Comment: @pyd Yes, you can get the entire URL as a string. But then you have to parse it manually, because if you try to pass it to any standard parser, it's going to give you back the same problem you started with.

Comment: you mean `localhost:8200/flip/<string:url>` ? , this also not works it extract only the string till '?'

Comment: @pyd No, that's not what I meant. If you're suggesting changing things to send `url` as a path component (endpoint) rather than a query parameter, that _would_ make things a little easier. But it seems like a bit of an abuse (isn't `flip` really the endpoint, not `flip/url`?). And you still need to percent-encode the URL anyway, or you're still sending an invalid query string. Why can't you just send the query string properly from the client?